# Show/hide multiple value in Microsoft Report Service

Tags: reporting-services, expression, visibility, show-hide, microsoft-reporting

I'm in the process of creating a report in Microsoft Report Services and I have a one problem. My report is to show max, min, avg temperature in specified room. I need to make such a filter values: when I select one value of parameter (e.g. min temperature) must to show this one value in the chart and table, when I select two value (e.g. min and max temperature) must to show this two values etc. I have a problem with Expression. My parameter have a multiply values and when I write sign "=" is error. I have no idea how this show or hidden values...

This Expression http://i62.tinypic.com/2s6m4o7.png is ok, when in parameter properties is http://pl.tinypic.com/?t=postupload and isn't move when I choice allow multiply values...

Comment: Can you not set the parameter to accept multiple values?  Then just set the available values to the Min, Med, Max (or whatever).  Then in your dataset, your Where statement can use an 'In' statement:
IE: Where TempRange In(MyParameter)

Comment: @craig.white thank you for your answer. In my dataset is query: 'EXECUTE dbo.ReportTemperature at data_start, at data_stop' . I don't have Where...IN... My values show in my parameter http://i61.tinypic.com/68sb2s.png , but when I select the value is error http://i60.tinypic.com/9tg6xu.png

Comment: Ah, Stored Procedure.  In that case I would forgo adding a parameter to your dataset (If you can't do it at the SQL server level, you're getting it all anyway) and focus on Filtering.  Do you have a Tablix or Matrix that you are displaying the results in?  Or ???    Any chance you could upload the rdl?